# HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver configure

Tags: java

spring session java xml configure 
 xml file configure  no auto write SpringHttpSessionConfiguration ->setHttpSessionIdResolver

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig" id="jedisPoolConfig">
</bean>
<bean id="jedisConnFactory"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      p:use-pool="true">
    <property name="hostName" value="192.168.0.87"/>
    <property name="port" value="6379"/>
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean
        class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver" factory-method="xAuthToken"
      id="httpSessionIdResolver"/>
```

Did not get the session from the head after configuration

Answer (score 0):

replace

But don't understand why